# How to invoke shell commands with pipes using subprocess.run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have the following code in a Python script

```
    inputfile = sys.argv[1];

    subprocess.run(["cat",
            inputfile, "| sh script1.sh | sh script2.sh | uniq  > outputfile.txt"], check=True, shell=True)
```

Currently, it just hangs if I run it.  What am I doing wrong?  My guess is that the inputfile argument is not correct.

Comment: You can use `subprocess.getstatusoutput()` or `subprocess.getoutput()` to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using `shell=True`, the first argument to `subprocess.run` should be a *string*, not a *list*. When you pass a list, only the first element is used, so your invocation is equivalent to:

```
subprocess.run("cat", check=True, shell=True)
```

...which will, of course, just hang forever waiting for input.

**Update**

So your command would look something like:

```
subprocess.run("cat {} | sh script1.sh | sh script2.sh | uniq  > outputfile.txt".format(inputfile),
               check=True, shell=True)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks

Comment: so...how do I pass the arguments to subprocess.run?

Comment: I had hoped that was clear, but I've updated the answer with an example that should help.